# Android Studio unknown Green Text on Fragment

Tags: android, firebase

i accidentally clicked something that i dont know, and it is so annoying..

how to remove this greentext??

[this green text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J78oR.png)

Answer (score 1):

But if you type /** before the method declaration and press Enter, the javadoc comment block will be generated automatically.

Read [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html) for more information.